# Write a SQL Log procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to write a simple SQL log procedure, that could be called like this:

```
Log("This is my param1 = {0}, param2 = {1} and param3('{2}')", 
     @param1, @param2, @param3)
```

the output should be redirected to the file on SQL Server "C:\output.txt"

is it possible using such a procedure with ***variable*** number of params and how?

perhaps I could use

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'echo created > c:\output.txt'
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'echo appended data >> c:\output.txt'
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'echo more data >> c:\output.txt'
```

Comment: ...Umm, how would **SQL** know to use multiple parameters?  And this almost looks like something that would be called outside SQL anyways (especially because you don't generally have 'access' to the actual files the system maintains).  How are you planning on calling this?

Comment: I need a 'universal' SQL server-side function to log information for debugging stored procedures. I need to "debug" some information in a file. I know there are a lot of other options to debug, however I like to write in a txt file.

Comment: For security and other reasons, SQL Server does not generally support sending output to a file, though there are a few slow and kludgy ways to force it (like `xp_CmdShell`).  In general, if you want to log stuff from SQL Server, you would be better off logging it to 1) a table, 2) the SQL Server error log, or 3) the system event log.   All of these are supported and relatively easy.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, SQL Server's T-SQL doesn't allow variable number of arguments to stored procedures *like how Java supports*. But since SQL Server 2005 has XML data type, you can build a simple XML with your arguments and send that as the second parameter, first being the log statement with placeholders. In your stored procedure, you can read those values back from XML.

Secondly, xp_cmdshell requires you to have 'sa' permissions, afaik. Instead, you could write those log statements to a temporary table and get a stored procedure created by your admin that takes the table name and the filepath and dumps the contents of the table to the filepath specified.

*Edited the comment about variable number of arguments as per one of the comments below*

Comment: I need to use this log in debugging stored procedures, that can be called with transactions. When I rollback the transaction, any lines from the log tables will be roll-backed... in the text file I have all the traces...

Comment: SQL Server allows nesting of transactions. So, you could start your own transaction in the logging procedure and commit it once you are done. Then the outcome of the enclosing transaction wouldn't affect your call to the log procedure.

Comment: Stored procedures can permit a variable number of arguments in the form of optional parameters.  What it cannot do is to allow an unlimited variable number of arguments like a parameter array does.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have a finite number of parameters, you can use nullable parameters in SQL server to implement optional parameters

So

```
create proc prcLog
    @Format varchar(1000),
    @p1 varchar(100) = null,
    @p2 varchar(100) = null,
    @p3 varchar(100) = null,
    ....

exec prcLog '{0}', 'a'
exec prcLog '{0} : {1}', 'a', 'b'
```

Given the amount of File IO and string manipulation, a CLR stored procedure may be a better option